# Where can I find a documentation about Ripper sexp output ? (Ruby AST)

Tags: ruby, jruby

whitequark [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894763/extract-the-ast-from-a-ruby-block) gave an accurate answer about how to get a ruby AST : the answer is Ripper, included in standard Ruby library.

However, I played a little with Ripper, but I have not find a documentation about the content/structure of the AST itself.

So my question is : where can I find a concise documentation about Ripper sexp output ?

Comment: As a side note, AST is not the same thing as s-expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No explicit documentation on Ripper exists, as Ripper is just an interface to MRI's yacc/bison parser. You can read the [source](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/parse.y?v=1.9.2#688), through; all the identifiers mentioned with `%type <node>` may appear in Ripper's sexps.

The MRI sources aren't an easy read, through, and I'd recommend determining the structure by trial and error: it may actually be faster that way.

You may be interested in this [article](http://carboni.ca/blog/p/Regex-Search-on-Arbitrary-Sequences), through, and also YARD uses [some code](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/blob/master/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb) based on Ripper. While that's not exactly what you need (i.e. the docs), these links contain some useful clues.